# Using wolfram alpha to solve IVP

Tags: wolfram-alpha

How can wolfram alpha be used to find the solution to an IVP, if the IVP has non integers in the condition
For example,
[image]
The half in the function was changed to multiply outside(it does this for any noninteger)
[image]
But as shown above works for any integer.

Comment: Just change your input: $a'(b)=2*b / a^3, a(0.5)=1$ You always have to check how your input is interpreted.

Comment: The problem is that in both other cases where you used $a$, you used it without an argument - its dependence on $b$ was implicit. WA assumed that your final use of $a$ was the same, and the (0.5) was a multiplier, in parentheses because of the radix. In addition to callculus's method, you can make every reference to $a$ be explicit in its dependence on $b$: `da(b)/db = 2*b/a(b)^3, a(.5) = 1`